# How should I add functionality to an object that already exists?

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, adapter

I have an interface that has a certain amount of well-defined functionality. Let's say:

```
interface BakeryInterface {
  public function createCookies();
  public function createIceCream();
}
```

This works well for most implementations of the interface, but in a few instances, I need to add some new functionality (like perhaps rolled into a new method, `createBrownies()`). The obvious/naive approach to doing this would be to extend the interface:

```
interface BrownieBakeryInterface extends BakeryInterface {
  public function createBrownies();
}
```

But has a pretty big downside in that I can't add the new functionality without modifying the existing API (like changing the class to use the new interface).

I was thinking about using an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to add the functionality after instantiation:

```
class BrownieAdapter {
  private brownieBakery;

  public function construct(BakeryInterface bakery) {
    this->brownieBakery = bakery;
  }

  public function createBrownies() {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Which would net me something like:

```
bakery = new Bakery();
bakery = new BrownieBakery(bakery);
bakery->createBrownies();
```

This seems like a good solution to the problem, but I'm wondering if I'm awakening the old gods by doing it. Is the adapter the way to go? Is there a better pattern to follow? Or should I really just be biting the bullet and just extending the original interface?

Comment: Delphi has helper classes, it is like adding methods to existing classes without really modifying them. For example Delphi has a TBitmap class defined in its graphics unit, you can create a helper class that adds, say, a Flip function to TBitmap. As long as the helper class is in scope you can call MyBitmap.Flip;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any of the [Handle Body patterns](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HandleBodyPattern) could fit the description, depending on your exact requirements, language, and needed level of abstraction.

The purist approach would be the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), which does exactly what you are looking for, dynamically add responsibilities to objects. If you are actually building bakeries, it's definitely overkill and you should just go with Adapter.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed: I realized using an adapter would screw with dependency injection, but using a decorator gets around that.

Answer (score 5):

Investigate the concept of **horizontal reuse**, where you can find stuff such as [**Traits**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), the still experimental but already production-proof [**Aspect Oriented Programming**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and the sometimes hated [**Mixins**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

A direct way of adding methods to a class also depends on the programming language. Ruby allows for [**monkey-patching**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) while Javascript's [**prototype-based**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) inheritance, where classes don't really exist, you create an object and just copy it and keep adding to it, e.g.:

```
var MyClass = {
    do : function(){...}
};

var MyNewClass = new MyClass;
MyClass.undo = function(){...};


var my_new_object = new MyNewClass;
my_new_object.do();
my_new_object.undo();
```

Finally, you can also emulate horizontal reuse, or runtime "modification" and "addition" of class/object behavior with [**reflection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 4):

If there is a requirement that `bakery` instance must change its behaviour dynamically (depending on the user actions, etc.) then you should go for the **Decorator pattern**.

If `bakery` does not change its behaviour dynamically but you cannot modify the `Bakery class` (external API, etc.) then you should go for the **Adapter pattern**.

If `bakery` does not change its behaviour dynamically and you can modify `Bakery class` then you should extend existing interface (as you initially proposed) or introduce a **new interface** `BrownieInterface` and let `Bakery` implement two interfaces `BakeryInterface` and `BrownieInterface`. 

Otherwise you gonna add unnecessary complexity to your code (using the Decorator pattern) for no good reason!

Answer (score 2):

You have encountered the expression problem. [This article by Stuart Sierra](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-clojure-protocols/index.html?ca=drs-) discusses clojures solution, but he also gives an example in Java and lists the popular solutions in classic OO.

[There's also this presentation by Chris Houser](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Clojure-Expression-Problem) that discusses pretty much the same ground.